# Can't unfocus databound combobox

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox

I'm trying to create a simple data application for a school project, in which an user selects data from an databound combobox for and fills out several textboxes for it to be committed to the database. However, when after I databind the combobox, and select an item, it simply will not let the user select something else. It's impossible to let edit anything, since the focus doesn't go away from the combobox.

What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the solution. All I had to do was to set the ComboBox's CausesValidation to false.